# How to convert .AFBRUSHES files to .ABR files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, affinity-designer, file-conversion

I have brush files with the extension '.AFBRUSHES' And I realized they belong to Affinity.
Is there a way to convert them to .ABR files, or another way I can use them as brushes in Photoshop?

I tried to Google all sorts of phrases, but he insists on bringing me only the opposite results: how to convert a Photoshop brush to an affinity ...

Comment: I very much doubt there is a converter

Comment: Is there a way to extract any content from these files?

Comment: What does the Affinity brush actually do?  You may find there is already a similar PS ABR brush set. There are literally thousands of Photoshop brushes available online to choose from, or you can simply make your own from scratch.